# Angular ui router - fixed menu with dynamic content

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have to create a page with a fixed top menu containing some input and buttons.

Depending on which data is filled in and which button is pressed, a map with data should appears below the menu.

The menu will always be there and only the map will be updated.

**ROUTE**

```
$stateProvider
.state('login', {
    url : '/login',
    templateUrl : 'app/login/login.html',
    controller : 'LoginController'
})
.state('home', {
    url : '/home',
    templateUrl : 'app/home/home.html'
})
.state('menu', {
    url : '',
    templateUrl : 'app/menu/menu.html',
    parent : 'home'
});
```

**home.html**

```
<div ui-view="menu"></div>

<h1 class="ui huge header">
    Please select something
</h1>
```

For the moment I can only see the "Please select something" but not the menu.

After that, how can I replace "Please select something" by the needed map ? Is it possible to have a default view ? When landing on home I should see the message and not a map

**EDIT**
Here is what I got after the answers

**ROUTE**

```
$stateProvider
.state('login', {
    url : '/login',
    views : {
        'login' : {
            templateUrl : 'app/login/login.html',
            controller : 'LoginController'
        }
    }
})
.state('home', {
    url : '/home',
    views : {
        'menu' : {
            templateUrl : 'app/menu/menu.html'
        },
        'content' : {
            templateUrl : 'app/home/home.html',
        }
    }
})
.state('home.other', {
    url : '/other',
    views : {
        'content@' : {
            templateUrl : 'app/home/home.html'
        }
    }
});
```

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<div ui-view="login"></div>

<div ui-view="menu"></div>
<div ui-view="content"></div>
```

It is working well but it is the best way to do it ? I have a lot of different content so I will have to duplicate the menu view inside every state ?

If I have a page with a different layout (without menu and content) - Should I just add a new `<div ui-view="list"></div>` in `index.html` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED**  according to question update

Try to read [Nested views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/nested-states-%26-nested-views#nested-states--views) this article to better understand existing solution in ui-router.

Here is example what you can do to avoid duplication of routes:

```
$stateProvider
.state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    views: {
        'login': {
            templateUrl: 'app/login/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginController'
        }
    }
})
.state('menu', {
    url: '/menu',
    templateUrl: 'app/menu/menu.html'
})
.state('menu.content', {
    views: {
        'default': {
            url: '/default',
            template: '<h1>Please select something</h1>'
        },
        'content1': {
            url: '/content1',
            templateUrl: 'app/content1/content1.html'
        },
        'content2': {
            url: '/content2',
            templateUrl: 'app/content2/content2.html'
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see very clear to read and understand from url what is inside and why. If you will have url `menu/content1` - that's mean under your menu is content1 visible right now.

Comment: What about the menu ?

Comment: @Weedoze, as I understood menu should be top level route. So you will have neted routing , with default route - `menu.default`. And while you change something in menu it will change route. Let me know if you want me to make an example.

Comment: @Weedoze, no need to duplicate menu, there is such thing like nested routing. Idea that you will have `menu` state and then from it state - `content` which will includes different views. Let me update my answer

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to define another state for the the menu just add it to your home state as another view. Like this

```
.state('home', {

    url: '/home',
    views:{

        'menu': {
            templateUrl: 'app/menu/menu.html'
        },

        'home': {
            templateUrl: 'app/home/home.html'
        }

    }
})
```

And change your HTML to this:

```
<div ui-view="menu"></div>
<div ui-view="home"></div>
```

And whenever you want to update the view (keeping the menu the same), create a state for that view like this:

```
.state('home.newState', {

    url: '/newState',
    views:{
        'home@':{
            templateUrl: 'app/home/newState.html'
        }
    }

})
```

This will update the view by adding the newState.html template in place of home.html template keeping the menu same.

Comment: What do you mean by "Change your HTML" ? Which file ?

Comment: Tthe main HTML file where you are loading all your scripts and css files.

Comment: index.html ? And then how can I handle the login page ?

Comment: You can create a state for the login page and add it as <div ui-view="login"></div>

Comment: You won't have to duplicate your menu view in every state if you use child states like instead of other, use home.other and just update the view for the content and not the menu. But if you make independent states you will have to add the menu to the view separately each time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121907/discussion-between-weedoze-and-mohit-yadav).

Comment: Answer edited again but not working. The url "/other" redirect to login page